# TLabel OnMouseDown event not firing in Firemonkey

Tags: android, ios, delphi, touch, firemonkey

I'm trying to change a `TLabel` color when the user touches it, but it looks like the `MouseDown` event is not being fired.

```
procedure TForm_Master.tv_1Down(Sender: TObject;
  Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
begin
tv_1.FontColor := TAlphaColors.Dodgerblue;
end;
```

What could possibly be going wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If we set `HitTest` to `True`, this control captures all mouse `OnClick` and `OnDblClick` events.

If we set `HitTest` to `False`, these two mouse-click events will pass through this control, so that a control laid out behind this one receives the mouse events instead of this control.

For most controls, `HitTest` is `True` by *default*. However, this is not true for `TLabel` and `TPathLabel`, where `HitTest` is False by default; these two controls do not capture the `OnClick` and `OnDblClick` events unless you set `HitTest` to `True`.

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/FMX.Controls.TControl.HitTest

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Machado's solution does not appear to work when using styles and programmatically created labels.

In such cases, it is easier to create a button style that looks like a label (e.g. in the StyleBook set its background opacity to 0), and then use the styled button instead of a label.

In your case the TNotifyEvent event you fire by setting the OnClick property of the styled button would then change the style of any objects as needed. Using styles can help maintain a consistent look. E.g. place the TStyleBook in an empty form, and inherit the app's other froms from that base form.